# Поменять соседей

Tags: python

Дан список с числами, необходимо поменять соседние элементы местами, т.е. `A[0]` с `A[1]`, `A[2]` с `A[3]`, и т.д. Распечатать получившийся список. Если список содержит нечётное число элементов, оставить последний элемент на месте.

Выводит ошибку `IndexError`

```
a = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
for i in range(len(a)):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        a[i], a[i + 1] = a[i + 1], a[i]
print(" ".join([str(i) for i in a]))
```

Comment: Никаких ошибок не выводит ни на чётном, ни на нечётном, ни на пустом массиве.

Comment: А вот ваш последний код стал неправильный и вывел-таки ошибку. Верните тот код, который был перед правкой вопроса — он ошибку не выдавал. И вроде бы даже правильно работал.

Comment: Поменял код в вопросе, почему если проверять через i % 2 выдает ошибку?

Comment: Потому что на нечётной длине массива `i` для последнего элемента будет чётным и `i + 1` выйдет за пределы массива.

Comment: Спасибо, понял.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
for i in range(len(a)-1):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        a[i], a[i + 1] = a[i + 1], a[i]
print(" ".join([str(i) for i in a]))
```

Comment: Запустите сами этот код хотя бы раз.

Comment: `range(len(a))-1` - единицу нужно вычитать от длины, а не от `range`

Answer (score 1):

На мой взгляд, более простое решение:

```
a = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
for i in range(0, len(a)-1, 2):
    a[i], a[i+1] = a[i+1], a[i]
print(" ".join([str(i) for i in a]))
```